# React Native: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.touchActive')"

Tags: react-native

We are getting the following error in our React Native application in production:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.touchActive')
```

`d` probably refers to a minified object identifier, but we're wondering if anyone out there has experienced a similar issue?

Or if anyone knows the conditions under which React Native might try to access `touchActive`?

Comment: touchActive prob has something to do with a Touchable/Button component or onPress function